# Why does GMail smtp configuration result in a 'Failure sending mail' error?

Tags: vb.net, email, smtp

Here is my code.

```
    Dim SmtpServer As New Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 25)
    SmtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("xxxxxx@gmail.com", "xxxxxxxxxx")
    Dim email As New Net.Mail.MailMessage("xxxxxx@gmail.com", _to, _subject, _message)
    email.Subject = _subject
    email.Body =
       "<html>" & _
       "<head>" & _
       "<meta http-equiv=""Content-Language"" content=""fr"">" & _
       "<meta http-equiv=""Content-Type"" content=""text/html; charset=windows-1252"">" & _
       "</head>" & _
       "<body>" & _
       _message & _
       "</body>" & _
       "</html>"
    SmtpServer.EnableSsl = True

    Try
        SmtpServer.Send(email)
        Return "OK"
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return ex.Message
    End Try
```

Comment: What is your question again? WHAT exactly is the error you encounter?

Comment: I found this exception message : "Failure sending mail"

Comment: Do you have SMTP enabled in your gmail settings ?

Comment: Set smtpserver.usedefaultcredentials=false